# How to check the value of any row in a group after a previous one fulfils a condition?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dataset grouped by test subjects that is filled according to the actions they perform. I need to find which customer does A and then, at some point, does B; but it doesn't necessarily have to be in the next action/row. And it can't be first does B and then A, it has to be specifically in that order. For example, I have this table:

```
Subject   ActionID  ActionOrder
1         A         1
1         C         2
1         D         3
1         B         4
1         C         5
2         D         1
2         A         2
2         C         3
2         B         4
3         B         1
3         D         2
3         A         3
4         A         1
```

Here subjects 1 and 2 are the ones that fulfil the order of actions condition. While 3 does not because it performs the actions in reverse order. And 4 only does action A

How can I get only subjects 1 and 2 as results? Thank you very much

Comment: What if a subject performs an action multiple times?

Comment: It counts as done once, nothing happens if you repeat, only the order of the actions. Whether 2 or 3 or more in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Subject
FROM tablename
WHERE ActionID IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Subject
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN ActionID = 'A' THEN ActionOrder END) <
       MIN(CASE WHEN ActionID = 'B' THEN ActionOrder END)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c8cd6fbbcd6541b092679e85e0988f5c).

Comment: It works, is it reproducible if you want to check more than two conditions?

Comment: @Juriv you can have as many conditions as you want if you adjust the WHERE and the HAVING clauses.

Comment: But from my, limited, knowledge, by using MAX and MIN you are closing yourself to only two possibilities, right? You can't check intermediate values between the minimum and the maximum. Soory if I sound as a newbie, I am primarily a non tech researcher

Comment: @Juriv this is conditional aggregation. With `MAX(CASE WHEN ActionID = 'A' THEN ActionOrder END)` you get the value of `ActionID = 'A'` for each subject and with `MIN(CASE WHEN ActionID = 'A' THEN ActionOrder END)` you get the value of `ActionID = 'B'` for each subject. In your case there is no difference between MIN and MAX if A and B have not duplicates inside the same subject. So this has nothing to do with MIN or MAX of a subject.

Comment: So if I want to check if someone does A, then B, then C? Like Subject 1

Comment: @Juriv Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b8949588106f79eea778564c35a3887

Answer (score 1):

Consider below option

```
select Subject 
from (
  select Subject, 
    regexp_replace(string_agg(ActionID, '' order by ActionOrder), r'[^AB]', '') check
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by Subject
)
where not starts_with(check, 'B')
and check like '%AB%'
```

Above assumes that Subject can potentially do same actions multiple times that's why few extra checks in `where` clause. Other wise it would be just `check = 'AB'`

Comment: Thank you very much, I will use both approaches depending on whether the process is more complex or simpler.